# Specific Process Between Supplicant and Router

Tags: router

So lets say I have a laptop which connects through a Wireless Access Point which is then connected to a router.

I'm trying to figure out if this happens as a result of an ARP response using the MAC address or, if the laptop uses the IP address to find the router. I know most models have switches built into them so lets negate that for this.

Does that mean that the laptop explicitly uses the IP address to find the router and will only use the MAC address if it needs to traverse through a switch somewhere else in the topology?

Thanks in advance. This is quite a difficult topic to find information on.

Comment: um... what is the question? Like, how does the ETHERNET work, or how does DHCP work or what?

Comment: How does the laptop forward PDU's onto the router through a wireless access point? Does it use the IP address or the MAC address. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

First lets rewrite your question to:
Question 1: *How does a wireless lan (WiFi) connection differ from a wired connection?*
Question 2: *Does a WiFi connection transmit data directly to the router's IP, or does it uses the MAC address?*
Question 3: *Does a Laptop forward PDU's into the router through the wireless access point? does it than use the IP or MAC?*

Assumption, PDU refers to [Protocol Data Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit)

Awnser question 1:
To understand how WIFI works, we first need to understand how a Wired network works. For this we use the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Description%20of%20OSI%20layers).

[image: OSI model from blackmoreops.com]

The PDU for each of the 7 layers in the model is different and dependent on what that layer represent.

Layer 1 (Physical) is all about electrical signals, Frequencies, voltages, amplitudes and the likes. it defines how we transmit the data down a wire (or through the ether), in this layer there is no network. All communication is from node to node
(so like

- "switch <=> switch"
- "switch <=> Accesspoint"
- "Accesspoint <=> Laptop"
- Etcetera

)
This layer does not (normally) have any security or encryption.

Layer 2 (Data Link) is the layer were we start to get a network.
 In this layer we start to see structures in the data (the PDU's are called frames) and we get addresses (MAC) Data can now only travel within this physical network (also known as subnet). Encryption is possible but not often implemented outside of the Enterprise networks.

Layer 3 (Network) is where we start to really get interesting. We have all the parts now to build networks and networks of networks (internet).
This layer's PDU is called a packet and its address is an IP address. 
From this point on we can make connections that span over multiple hops though different networks with the so called routing scheme's.

Now to WiFi has the following changes to this standard model:
Layer 1: this is wireless (through the ether) so we get channels, bands, frequency and interference. It means that besides how to encode the bits we also have to dial a transceiver. to facilitate this there is a mechanism that uses names for humans to identify networks (SSID).
also because normally we do not have encryption anyone could just see all your data , WiFi adds an encryption scheme to this layer to ensure only authorized devices can communicate on it. (WPA for example)

Answer question 2: 
  WiFI is on layer 1, so it does not connected to anything but what is directly connected to itself (ergo WiFi is only on the ether), the router is on a different connection. We need at least layer 2 to communicate with it (using MAC addresses) or if we want to send data to other networks we need at least layer 3 and an IP address.

Answer question 3: 
 Well, for data to be transmitted to other networks (a router connects at least 2 networks) we need layer 3 and an IP address. so the only way your laptop can transmit data like this we use IP addresses.

Footnote:
 To learn more about all this you could capture the data transmitted in your own network (DO not capture data on other people there network this is often illegal consult your local law proffesional!). To capture this data Wireshark is a great tool. you can see all this in action in it.